# How to solve an equation y=ax^2+bx+c when x is unknown and y known

Tags: r, function, equation

I have this equation:

y = -0.00248793*x^2+20.77173764*x-371.01805798

And I would like to obtain the result of the equation when I give "y" numbers,

**edited explanation 2/06/20:**
I want to add a vector as my "y", and receive an output of one vector also.

This problem is a biological one, in which I performed citokine bead array (CBA) and I stablished a reference curve which is sinusoidal.

after stablishing the degree of the equation making the following:

```
fitil6_1=lm(Standards$`IL6 median`~poly(concentration,1,raw=TRUE))
fitil6_2=lm(Standards$`IL6 median`~poly(concentration,2,raw=TRUE))
fitil6_3=lm(Standards$`IL6 median`~poly(concentration,3,raw=TRUE))  
fitil6_4=lm(Standards$`IL6 median`~poly(concentration,4,raw=TRUE))



lines(concentration,predict(fitil6_1,data.frame(x=concentration)),col="red")
lines(concentration,predict(fitil6_2,data.frame(x=concentration)),col="green") 
lines(concentration,predict(fitil6_3,data.frame(x=concentration)),col="blue")
lines(concentration,predict(fitil6_4,data.frame(x=concentration)),col="purple)
legend(20,40000,legend=c("de grau 1","de grau 2","de grau 3","de grau 4"),lty=1,col=c("red","green","blue","purple"))
```

I have chosen the degree 2 formula as it fits better to my dots for this cytokine (and most cytokines in this study)

So when I make

```
coef(fitil6_2)

 (Intercept)        poly(concentration, 2, raw = TRUE)1  poly(concentration, 2, raw = TRUE)2
-8.262381e+02                              2.371377e+01                       -2.847135e-03
```

I receive that output and then I am able to build the formula (in this case):

y=-2.847135e-03 *x^2+2.371377e+01*x-8.262381e+02

but as my independent value is what I know is pretty difficult to isolate x!
**(end of the editing)**

I have tried many things like making function(x,y) but when you specify this you need to give a number of y, so really I am litlle bit lost!

Thank you

Comment: Time to pull out an algebra textbook and read about the quadratic equation.

Comment: This question will be more appropriate for math.stackexchange

Answer (score 2):

As @Dave2e said, you can solve this particular example by algebra.  But you might need a programmatic solution, or you might be using the quadratic as an easy example.  in which case...

Rewrite your problem as "what value of y satisfies -0.00248793*x^2+20.77173764*x-371.01805798 - y = 0?".

There are plenty of ways to find the zeroes of a function.  That's what you've turned your problem into.  Suppose your "known value of y" is 10...

```
f <- function(x, y) {
  -0.00248793*x^2+20.77173764*x-371.01805798 - y
}

answer <- stats::uniroot(f, interval=c(0, 50), y=10)

# Check we've got the right answer
f(answer$root, 10)
```

Giving

```
[1] -1.186322e-10
```

Using this method, you do need to find/guess a range within which the answer might lie.  That's the purpose of the `interval=c(0.50)` part of the call to `uniroot`.  You can read the online help for more information about the value returned by `uniroot` and things you might want to look out for.

Comment: Thank you yes as @Dave2e I have tried also in this way but I had problems also, well thank you I think this will work for me!

Comment: Excuse me again I don't know if it's is working properly, when I introduce a vector a warning message popped up:

Error in stats::uniroot(f, interval = c(0, 50), y = citoquines_valero$`IL10 median`) : 
  f() values at end points not of opposite sign
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In if (is.na(f.lower)) stop("f.lower = f(lower) is NA") :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (is.na(f.upper)) stop("f.upper = f(upper) is NA") :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: You really need to make a simple, self-contained example including input data, sample code and expected output.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) may be helpful.  Nonetheless, I see at least two potential issues: (1) for at least one element of `citoquines_valero$IL10 median`, `c(0, 50)` does not contain the zero. The solution to this problem is given in the online help.  Have you read it?  (2)  `uniroot` is not vectorised, which is why you're getting the "length > 1" warning.

Comment: I think I need to read it more calmly because my first impression is that I don't understand, but well I will keep trying and if not I will make a better post. I will read that also thank you.

Thank you really for your help!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all who answered I have just started in this page, this worked for me:

isolating "y" and then making a function with the quadratic formula to x:

````
   delta<-function(y,a,b,c)
   {k=(-b+sqrt(b^2-4*a*(c-y)))/(2*a)
   print(k)
   }

delta(citoquines_valero$`IFNg median`,-1.957128e-03,1.665741e+01,-7.522327e+02)

#I will use that one as a provisional solution.
#I have also been told to use this, but is not working properly:

result <- function(y,a,b,c){
  # Constructing delta
  delta<-function(y,a,b,c){
    b^2-4*a*(c-y)
  }
  if(delta(a,b,d) > 0){ # first case D>0
    x_1 = (-b+sqrt(delta(y,a,b,c)))/(2*a)
    x_2 = (-b-sqrt(delta(y,a,b,c)))/(2*a)
    if (x_1 >= 0) {
      print(x_1)
      else if (x_2 >= 0){
        print(x_2)
      }
    }
    print(result)
    else if(delta(a,b,d) == 0){ # second case D=0
      x = -b/(2*a); return(x)
    }
    else {"There are no real roots."}; # third case D<0```
    return("There are no real roots.")
  }
}
````